# How to display the all available commands in oracle database?

Tags: oracle

I would like to check whether some commands available in database, Is there any command dictionary like that in db apart from Oracle documention?

Comment: why don't you want to look in the documentation?

Comment: I am just finding another way to do it.

Comment: great so you have a list, how doe this help you? surely you will need to know what each command does, and for that the place to look is in the documentation.

Comment: Yes obviously..I did not say I won't look at documentation ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check view `SELECT * FROM V$RESERVED_WORDS`